# Morphia update recursive document

Tags: mongodb, morphia

I currently have a model that has an array of objects of the same type as a field. These objects in the array can have their own children of the same type, and so on.

I'm trying to, using Morphia, update an object N levels down in the hierarchy. What I do is keep a reference to the ID of the "root" document. (The one that is actually queryable in Mongo) I then do a deep search for the sub-object I want to update, make changes to it and save the root.

However, this does not actually update the sub-object and I can't just do an update on it in the traditional sense because it's not its own document in Mongo, it's just nested. How can I achieve this?

I hope I've explained what I'm trying to do well enough.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you, i think that if you use dbref annotation, morphia do this automatically... but i'm not sure.

dbref will automatically do reference an document in another, "like" a "normal" relacional reference, if i understand, you're referencing documents manually...

try testing this, and tell us what you get.